# Vagrant under Windows 10 with VirtualBox - how to connect into created machine

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I run Vagrant version 2.0.1 with VirtualBox v. 5.2.2 under Windows 10, all is more or less the latest version.
I created machine from image ubuntu/xenial64 (latest version 20171201.0.0).
I updated all the packages and installed there MongoDB version 3.4.0.
I also exposed MongoDB ports in Vagrantfile.
I have no problem to access the DB from the host machine.

Now I want to create a new machine from this one as follows:

```
vagrant package --output mongodb.box
vagrant box add mongodb mongodb.box
rm mongodb.box
cd ..
mkdir mongodb
cd mongodb
vagrant init mongodb
vagrant up
```

Then I get repeating message "default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying..." until Vagrant says it won't connect.
I can't

```
vagrant ssh
```

into the machine, but if I enable mongodb ports in Vagrantfile I can access DB.

Is there another way how to create my own working and manageable machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked in %userhome%.vagrant.d\boxes\mongodb\0\virtualbox\Vagrantfile and there were no settings for

```
config.ssh.username
config.ssh.password
```

After I copied it from original xenial box it works fine.